# GroupBy column and filter rows with maximum value in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am almost certain this has been asked before, but [a search through stackoverflow](https://www.google.de/search?q=pyspark%20filter%20by%20max%20column%20value%20site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE735DE735&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFofPX3qrZAhUByqQKHUvvAN8QrQIINCgEMAA&biw=1536&bih=760&dpr=1.25) did not answer my question. Not a duplicate of [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218882/find-maximum-row-per-group-in-spark-dataframe) since I want the maximum value, not the most frequent item. I am new to pyspark and trying to do something really simple: I want to groupBy column "A" and then only keep the row of each group that has the maximum value in column "B". Like this:

```
df_cleaned = df.groupBy("A").agg(F.max("B"))
```

Unfortunately, this throws away all other columns - df_cleaned only contains the columns "A" and the max value of B. How do I instead keep the rows? ("A", "B", "C"...)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can do this without a `udf` using a `Window`.

Consider the following example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('a', 5),
    ('a', 8),
    ('a', 7),
    ('b', 1),
    ('b', 3)
]
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B"])
df.show()
#+---+---+
#|  A|  B|
#+---+---+
#|  a|  5|
#|  a|  8|
#|  a|  7|
#|  b|  1|
#|  b|  3|
#+---+---+
```

Create a `Window` to partition by column `A` and use this to compute the maximum of each group. Then filter out the rows such that the value in column `B` is equal to the max.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('A')
df.withColumn('maxB', f.max('B').over(w))\
    .where(f.col('B') == f.col('maxB'))\
    .drop('maxB')\
    .show()
#+---+---+
#|  A|  B|
#+---+---+
#|  a|  8|
#|  b|  3|
#+---+---+
```

Or equivalently using `pyspark-sql`:

```python
df.registerTempTable('table')
q = "SELECT A, B FROM (SELECT *, MAX(B) OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS maxB FROM table) M WHERE B = maxB"
sqlCtx.sql(q).show()
#+---+---+
#|  A|  B|
#+---+---+
#|  b|  3|
#|  a|  8|
#+---+---+
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this solution (Spark 2.4). I get:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: max(input[1, bigint, false]) windowspecdefinition(input[0, string, true], specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$()))`

Comment: @AltShift I suggest you create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) and write a new question. Be sure to mention you tried this solution and include the full traceback. (Are you sure you're using `pyspark.sql.functions.max` and not `__builtin__.max`?)

Comment: Thanks @pault I've just received advice form Databricks that it is an issue with Spark 2.4. When they come back to me with their final analysis I should create a question and answer for the community.

Comment: @AltShift; as someone that has hit the same bug, would it make sense to create the question already anyway so the rest of us have a place we can monitor for progress on this issue?

Comment: @Jeroen: Now documented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508608/using-where-on-f-max-overwindow-on-spark-2-4-throws-java-exception/54508646#54508646

Comment: might want to use dense_rank() instead of max() if you want to ensure uniqueness by group.  In my use case, i'm left joining the results of this back to to the original df to impute missings. The results need to be distinct.

Comment: Why is `withColumn("maxB")....drop("maxB")` necessary? I checked, and `df.where(f.col("B") == f.max("B").over(w)).show()` fails with an UnsupportedOperationException java error, but I don't understand pyspark's internals well enough to know why

Comment: @ZaneDufour not spark-sql, but I believe [this answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470849/why-are-aggregate-functions-not-allowed-in-where-clause).

Comment: @justincress that dense_rank() change does not ensure uniqueness, does it? If there are two rows with the maximum value for B, both would have dense_rank=1, right?

Answer (score 21):

Another possible approach is to apply join the dataframe with itself specifying "leftsemi".
This kind of join includes all columns from the dataframe on the left side and no columns on the right side.

For example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('a', 5, 'c'),
    ('a', 8, 'd'),
    ('a', 7, 'e'),
    ('b', 1, 'f'),
    ('b', 3, 'g')
]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"])
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  5|  c|
|  a|  8|  d|
|  a|  7|  e|
|  b|  1|  f|
|  b|  3|  g|
+---+---+---+
```

Max value of column B by by column A can be selected doing:

```
df.groupBy('A').agg(f.max('B')
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  a|  8|
|  b|  3|
+---+---+
```

Using this expression as a right side in a left semi join, and renaming the obtained column `max(B)` back to its original name `B`, we can obtain the result needed:

```
df.join(df.groupBy('A').agg(f.max('B').alias('B')),on='B',how='leftsemi').show()
+---+---+---+
|  B|  A|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  3|  b|  g|
|  8|  a|  d|
+---+---+---+
```

The physical plan behind this solution and the one from accepted answer are different and it is still not clear to me which one will perform better on large dataframes.

The same result can be obtained using spark SQL syntax doing:

```
df.registerTempTable('table')
q = '''SELECT *
FROM table a LEFT SEMI
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        A,
        max(B) as max_B
    FROM table
    GROUP BY A
    ) t
ON a.A=t.A AND a.B=t.max_B
'''
sqlContext.sql(q).show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  b|  3|  g|
|  a|  8|  d|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: The question was about getting the max value, not about keeping just one row. So actually this works with no regards on unique values in column B. Anyway if you want to keep only one row for each value of column A, you should go for `df.select("A","B",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("A").orderBy("B", ascending=False)).alias("rn")).filter("rn = 1")`

Comment: `ascending` isn't a method for `orderBy()`

Answer (score 8):

There are two great solutions, so I decided to benchmark them. First let me define a bigger dataframe:

```py
N_SAMPLES = 600000
N_PARTITIONS = 1000
MAX_VALUE = 100
data = zip([random.randint(0, N_PARTITIONS-1) for i in range(N_SAMPLES)],
          [random.randint(0, MAX_VALUE) for i in range(N_SAMPLES)],
          list(range(N_SAMPLES))
          )
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"])
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|118| 91|  0|
|439| 80|  1|
|779| 77|  2|
|444| 14|  3|
...
```

Benchmarking @pault's solution:

```py
%%timeit
w = Window.partitionBy('A')
df_collect = df.withColumn('maxB', f.max('B').over(w))\
    .where(f.col('B') == f.col('maxB'))\
    .drop('maxB')\
    .collect()
```

gives

```
655 ms ± 70.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Benchmarking @ndricca's solution:

```py
%%timeit
df_collect = df.join(df.groupBy('A').agg(f.max('B').alias('B')),on='B',how='leftsemi').collect()
```

gives

```
1 s ± 49.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, @pault's solution seems to be 1.5x faster. Feedbacks on this benchmark are very welcome.

Comment: Hey @Dan , that's the standard deviation. 655 ms ± 70.9 is faster than 1 s ± 49.1

Answer (score 3):

just want to add scala spark version of @ndricca´s answer in case anyone needs it:

```scala
val data = Seq(("a", 5,"c"), ("a",8,"d"),("a",7,"e"),("b",1,"f"),("b",3,"g"))
val df = data.toDF("A","B","C")
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  5|  c|
|  a|  8|  d|
|  a|  7|  e|
|  b|  1|  f|
|  b|  3|  g|
+---+---+---+

val rightdf = df.groupBy("A").max("B")
rightdf.show()
+---+------+
|  A|max(B)|
+---+------+
|  b|     3|
|  a|     8|
+---+------+

val resdf = df.join(rightdf, df("B") === rightdf("max(B)"), "leftsemi")
resdf.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  8|  d|
|  b|  3|  g|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Interesting, but perhaps not as relevant to a pyspark question?

Comment: I myself am searching for a way to achieve this in scala spark and landed on this question. I´m sure there is someone like me, just hope can save them time

Comment: I agree, I indeed would be happy if more people posted the alternative language solution (with a clear disclaimer that it is for another language) since Google's search algorithm often brings one to the wrong language, or questions are only answered in PySpark / Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to number the rows via `row_number()` using a window partitioned by `A` in the order of `B`.
This solution is close to the one by @pault, but when there are several rows with the maximum value, it only keeps one of them, which I find better.

Given the same example:

```
data = [
    ('a', 5),
    ('a', 8),
    ('a', 7),
    ('b', 1),
    ('b', 3)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B"])
df.show()
```

The `row_number` solution is:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy('B')
df_collect = df.withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(w)) \
    .filter(F.col('row_number') == 1) \
    .drop('row_number') \
    .show()

+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  a|  8|
|  b|  3|
+---+---+
```

---

I also extended the benchmark from @Fernando Wittmann, both solutions run in about the same time:

The dataframe:

```
N_SAMPLES = 600000
N_PARTITIONS = 1000
MAX_VALUE = 100
data = zip(
    [random.randint(0, N_PARTITIONS-1) for i in range(N_SAMPLES)],
    [random.randint(0, MAX_VALUE) for i in range(N_SAMPLES)],
    list(range(N_SAMPLES))
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"])
```

`row_number` approach:

```
%%timeit
w = Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy(F.col('B').desc())
df_collect = df.withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(w)) \
    .filter(F.col('row_number') == 1) \
    .drop('row_number') \
    .collect()
313 ms ± 19.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`== max` approach:

```
%%timeit
w = Window.partitionBy('A')
df_collect = df.withColumn('maxB', F.max('B').over(w))\
    .where(F.col('B') == F.col('maxB'))\
    .drop('maxB')\
    .collect()
328 ms ± 24.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`leftsemi` approach:

```
%%timeit
df_collect = df.join(df.groupBy('A').agg(F.max('B').alias('B')),on='B',how='leftsemi').collect()
516 ms ± 19.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: what is the size of the df you used in your benchmark?

Comment: @DerekO I've edited the answer with the dataframe generation code. It's 600K rows with 3 columns.