# PySpark reduceByKey by only one key

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a rdd like this

```
// Structure List[Tuple(x1, x2, value), Tuple(x1, x2, value)]
data = [('23', '98', 34), ('23', '89', 39), ('23', '12', 30), ('24', '12', 34), ('24', '14', 37), ('24', '16', 30)]
```

I am looking for the end result to be max value of score for x1 with x2 value associated with it. Like this

```
data = [('23', '89', 39), ('24', '14', 37)]
```

I tried `reduceByKey` but it is giving me max of each combinations which is not what I am looking for.

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987725/pyspark-reducebykey-by-only-one-key#comment90934629_51987725):

This is what I tried:

```
max_by_group = (
    data.map(lambda x: (x[0], x))
        .reduceByKey(lambda x1, x2: max(x1, x2, key=lambda x: x[-1])) 
        .values()
)
```

Comment: This is what I did
    max_by_group = (
        data.map(lambda x: (x[0], x))
        .reduceByKey(lambda x1, x2: max(x1, x2, key=lambda x: x[-1])) 
        .values()
    )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupBy` the first element, and then find the max value for each group by the third element in the tuple:

```
(rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x[0])
    .mapValues(lambda x: max(x, key=lambda y: y[2]))
    .values()
).collect()
# [('24', '14', 37), ('23', '89', 39)]
```

Or use `reduceByKey`:

```
(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x if x[2] > y[2] else y)
    .values()
).collect()
# [('24', '14', 37), ('23', '89', 39)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried both methods. It took a while since there were nearly billion records. But to my surprise reduceByKey was faster than groupBy not sure why. Also your solution of reduceByKey was almost same as mine :)

Comment: Yes `reduceByKey` is more efficient than `groupBy` when it's applicable, because `reduceByKey` is optimized and it combines data for each partition before shuffling; The shuffling after the by partition aggregation minimizes data transfer across the cluster, which is generally expensive.

Comment: Hmm I did not know that. Thank you very much for sharing this info.

Answer (score 2):

@Psidom's answer is what you're looking for if you're using `rdd`s. Another option is to [convert your `rdd` to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508083/difference-between-dataframe-in-spark-2-0-i-e-datasetrow-and-rdd-in-spark).

```python
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF(["x1", "x2", "value"])
df.show()
#+---+---+-----+
#| x1| x2|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#| 23| 98|   34|
#| 23| 89|   39|
#| 23| 12|   30|
#| 24| 12|   34|
#| 24| 14|   37|
#| 24| 16|   30|
#+---+---+-----+
```

Now you can [group by `x1` and filter the rows with the maximum `value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829993/groupby-column-and-filter-rows-with-maximum-value-in-pyspark/48830780#48830780):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('x1')
df.withColumn('maxValue', f.max('value').over(w))\
    .where(f.col('value') == f.col('maxValue'))\
    .drop('maxValue')\
    .show()
#+---+---+-----+
#| x1| x2|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#| 23| 89|   39|
#| 24| 14|   37|
#+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

from itertools import groupby:

```
[max(list(j),key=lambda x:x[2]) for i,j in groupby(data,key = lambda x:x[0])]

Out[335]: [('23', '89', 39), ('24', '14', 37)]
```

Comment: This works in python, but OP is asking about spark rdds.