# How to display the particular max row in pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code

```
ageDF.sort('Period')
     .groupBy('Period')
     .agg(round(sum('Age_specific_birth_rate'), 2).alias('Total Births'))
     .show()
```

The above groups the sum of age_specific_birth_rate by Period

So the output will be like

```
Period|Total Births|
+------+------------+
|  2000|       395.5|
|  2001|       393.4|
|  2002|       377.3|
|  2003|       386.2|
|  2004|       395.9|
|  2005|       391.9|
|  2006|       400.4|
|  2007|       434.0|
|  2008|       437.8|
|  2009|       425.7|
|  2010|       434.0|
|  2011|       417.8|
|  2012|       418.2|
|  2013|       400.4|
|  2014|       384.3|
|  2015|       398.7|
|  2016|       374.8|
|  2017|       362.7|
|  2018|       342.2|
```

But I wanna display the maximum among this by Period

so when I type in the follwing code

```
  ageDF.sort('Period')
       .groupBy('Period')
       .agg(round(sum('Age_specific_birth_rate'), 2).alias('Total'))
       .select('Period', 'Total')
       .agg(max('Total'))
       .show()
```

I get the output

```
> +----------+
  |max(Total)|
  +----------+
  |     437.8| 
  +----------+
```

But I wanna get something like

```
  +------+------------+
  |Period|max(Total)  |
  +------+------------+
  |  2008|       395.5|
```

What shuold I do ?

Thank you

Comment: That's a common problem. You want to output max value and the line that contains max value. Alternative way is for-loop your data and compare each one with max value, if they are equal then output this. There is probably multi answer.

Comment: Can you put a small initial dataset as an example and the output expected for that dataset to be able to reproduce and understand the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GroupBy column and filter rows with maximum value in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829993/groupby-column-and-filter-rows-with-maximum-value-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ageDF.sort('Period')
     .groupBy('Period')
     .agg(round(sum('Age_specific_birth_rate'), 2).alias('Total'))
     .orderBy(functions.col('Total').desc())
     .limit(1)
     .select('Period', 'Total')
     .show()
```