# Return the rows of a dataframe that satisfy one condition while fixing the values of another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Genres | Year | Number_Movies
Drama  |2015  | 705
Romance|2015  | 203
Comedy |2015  | 586
Drama  |2014  | 605
Romance|2014  | 293
Comedy |2014  | 786
```

I would like to return the gender by year that has the maximum number of movies:

```
Genres | Year | Number_Movies
Drama  |2015  | 705
Comedy |2014  | 786
```

Please help if possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GroupBy column and filter rows with maximum value in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829993/groupby-column-and-filter-rows-with-maximum-value-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few options that can solve this -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Drama',2015,705),('Romance',2015,203),('Comedy',2015,586),('Drama',2014,605),('Romance',2014,293),('Comedy ',2014,786)],['Genres','Year','Number_Movies'])
```

**First Option:** Define a rank using window function (partition by - Year and order by - Number_Movies desc). Highest Number_Movies each year will get rank "1".

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,desc

w = Window.partitionBy("Year").orderBy(desc("Number_Movies"))
rank = row_number().over(w).alias('rank')

df.withColumn("rank", rank)\
    .where("rank=1")\
    .drop("rank")\
    .show()

#+-------+----+-------------+
#| Genres|Year|Number_Movies|
#+-------+----+-------------+
#|Comedy |2014|          786|
#|  Drama|2015|          705|
#+-------+----+-------------+
```

**Second Option:** Get maxumum of Number_Movies for each year and self join with dataframe to get the Genres.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max,col

joining_condition = [col('a.Year') == col('b.Year'), col('a.max_Number_Movies') == col('b.Number_Movies')]

df.groupBy("Year").\
    agg(max("Number_Movies").alias("max_Number_Movies")).alias("a").\
    join(df.alias("b"),  joining_condition).\
    selectExpr("b.Genres","b.Year","b.Number_Movies").\
    show()

#+-------+----+-------------+
#| Genres|Year|Number_Movies|
#+-------+----+-------------+
#|Comedy |2014|          786|
#|  Drama|2015|          705|
#+-------+----+-------------+
```