# Could DataFrame.dropDuplicates used to keep only the latest data in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe sorted by `time` in Spark like this:

```
id     value     time
1      a         2024-01-01 00:00:00
2      a         2024-01-01 00:00:00
2      b         2024-01-03 00:00:00
1      b         2024-01-03 01:00:00
2      c         2024-01-03 02:00:00
```

And I want to deduplicate the Dataframe, for each id, only the latest record will be left. Like this:

```
id     value     time
1      b         2024-01-03 01:00:00
2      c         2024-01-03 02:00:00
```

I try to use `dataframe.dropDuplicates('id')` to achieve this, but seems it doesn't quite meet my requirement.

What's the rule for `dropDuplicates` to choose which record to keep? Is `dropDuplicates` always keeping the latest record or earliest record? Or did it just randomly choose one record to keep?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829993/groupby-column-and-filter-rows-with-maximum-value-in-pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think to use `Window` function? For example in this way?

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

w1 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(f.col("time").desc())
df.withColumn("row_num", f.row_number().over(w1)) \
  .filter(f.col("row_num") == 1) \
  .drop("row_num") \
  .show()
```