# symfony querybuilder group function

Tags: symfony

i want get rows individually with condition that sum of prizes equals to my parameter (price)
actually i want limit number of rows in prize entity
but i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function
```

this is my query :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('up')
        ->join('up.prize','prize')
        ->select()
        ->where('up.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('SUM(prize.prizeValue) <= :price')
        ->setParameters(['user'=>$user , 'price'=>$price])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $qb;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aggregate function in `WHERE` clause.

[Why are aggregate functions not allowed in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470849/why-are-aggregate-functions-not-allowed-in-where-clause/42471383)

Try this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('up')
        ->join('up.prize','prize')
        ->select('up')
        ->where('up.user = :user')
        ->having('SUM(prize.prizeValue) <= :price') // Replace with `having`
        ->setParameters(['user'=>$user , 'price'=>$price])
        ->groupBy('up') // `Group by` because you're using an aggregate
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $qb;
```

Comment: it works . but main problem is if condition is true it gives me all of prizes . i want restrict rows based on having condition . for example if price = 3000 . it must give me 3 row

Comment: This is as far as I can tell how to fix the problem you had. Only you know what parameters are you setting, what records you have in the base... Maybe it's the condition, maybe it's the database - I suggest you double-check all of those.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the **Where** condition to the **HAVING** clause

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('up')
        ->join('up.prize','prize')
        ->where('up.user = :user')
        ->having('SUM(prize.prizeValue) <= :price')
        ->groupBy('up.id')
        ->setMaxResults(5);
        ->setParameters(['user'=>$user , 'price'=>$price]);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: it works . but main problem is if condition is true it gives me all of prizes . i want restrict rows based on having condition . for example if price = 3000 . it must give me 3 row . without any setMaxResult