# Why cannot compare directly Salary < max(Salary) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write SQL query to get the second highest salary

```
select max(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary 
from  Employee 
where Salary<(select max(Salary) from Employee);
```

I would like to ask why cannot compare directly Salary < max(Salary) at the `where` in SQL?

Comment: It should work. are you getting any error?

Comment: Thank @mkRabbani for the reply. It works but I did not understand why  I Cant write:

```select max(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary 
from  Employee 
where Salary<max(salary);```

Comment: 'why cannot compare directly Salary < max(Salary) ' - That's just the way sql works , you have to declare what you want

Comment: Note that this isn't scalable; you cannot (easily) extend this method to grab the third highest salary

Comment: You must to know Order of Execution in Sql: (1) from clause is chose table --> (2) where clause is filter data --> select data. At the step 2 we do not have any data is select, it lead to Salary data is not define, that the reason you can't write query like that. More info: https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

Comment: this link should help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470849/why-are-aggregate-functions-not-allowed-in-where-clause/42471383

Comment: Thanks @PhongNguyễn for your explanation. You save my day, Man!

Comment: don't forget to upvote my comment if useful, have nice day man

Comment: *why cannot compare directly Salary < max(Salary) at the where in SQL?* The condition removes some records from output. This changes (decreases) maximal value. This causes more records remove, which cause ... until "no rows found". Do you need in such result really?

Comment: @TranTran . . . This is how SQL is defined.  You are free to invent and implement your own query language, but SQL does not allow aggregated and unaggregated references to the same column for the same table reference.